# WPF binding a usercontrol dynamically to another form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form in which I host a UserControl inside a Grid and bind it to a data context variable.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.FormDetails"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:Test.Nodez" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local1:MinimalApp}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="500">
   
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="800" Width="500" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=ActiveUserControl, BindsDirectlyToSource=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have a few different UserControls, and i need to load them dynamically into this form.
I have set binding as above, and the data context is:

```
namespace Test.Nodez
{
   

    public class MinimalApp : PropertyChangedBase
    {        

        public MinimalApp()
        {
            
            FormDetailFileIn detailFileIn = new FormDetailFileIn();
            ActiveUserControl = detailFileIn;
           
        }      
    
      
          
            private UserControl _activeUserControl;

            public UserControl ActiveUserControl
            {
                get => _activeUserControl;
                set
                {
                    // Only set the value if it has changed
                    if (_activeUserControl != value)
                    {
                        _activeUserControl = value;

                    // Signal to the control that it needs to update the value
                      Console.WriteLine(nameof(ActiveUserControl));
                        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActiveUserControl));
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    
}
```

When I update the `ActiveUserControl` variable, the `Console writeLines` print as expected, but the Form `UserControl` does not update. What am i missing with this binding?

Comment: I assume you tried with just `Content="{Binding ActiveUserControl}`? What is `PropertyChangedBase`? you would normally implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the view models. Are you sure the DataContext is correct? Unfortunately WPF is not great at generating meaningfull errors when you make some simple mistake.

Comment: Hi! Yup I initially tried that binding formatting. RIght click in the xaml sends me to the view model, so i assume it is correctly set up, I will try INotifyPropertyChanged ...

Comment: (I am integrating some third party code, which shows:   `public abstract class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged`
    ) SO I assume this is fine

Comment: It may help to create a minimal reproducible example. I would be somewhat careful with third party libraries, since it may not be apparent exactly how it works.

Comment: Thank you, I will break out the relevant code and debug further.

Comment: What exactly happens in that if check in the  setter when you debug?  Why bother with that if? Can the property be set with the same user control twice really anyhow?

Comment: `Binding ElementName=ActiveUserControl` makes no sense, there is no element with that name. You probably meant to write `Content="{Binding Path=ActiveUserControl}` (where setting BindsDirectlyToSource and UpdateSourceTrigger is pointless). Such a  Binding requires that the DataContext (and not only the design-time DataContext) is set to an instance of the class with the ActiveUserControl property.